# error: cannot find symbol: method createUriForFile(Context,File)

Tags: java, android, cordova

I've tried [NoodleOfDeath's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57599694/18342034) of [Cordova Android clicking input problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586259/cordova-android-clicking-input-type-file-brings-up-system-file-browser-not-came), but I faced with a problem: `"cannot find symbol"` for `createTempFile` and `createUriForFile` methods. As far as I understand I should import this methods, but google don't show any examples. Or it should be some library, which has these methods, or only [@NoodleOfDeath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409958/noodleofdeath) has required code. I would like to ask this question directly, but have no reputation make comments, so I have to create this thead.
Also I'am newbie in java, so I'm sorry if my question sounds stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. Not sure that this is the best way, but it works on my device with android 11, and cordova 9.0.
I've changed the try-catch block inside the body of onShowFileChoosermethod in NoodleOfDeath's solution.

```
    try {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_"+timeStamp+"_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg", storageDir);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Temporary photo capture file: " + tempFile);
        tempUri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);                              
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Temporary photo capture URI: " + tempUri);
        captureIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempUri);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Unable to create temporary file for photo capture", e);
        captureIntent = null;
    }
```

Comment: I have also changed a condition inside ```startActivityForResult``` block.

it was 
```if (intent == null && captureUri != null) {``` 
and now
```if ((intent == null || (intent.getData() == null && intent.getClipData() == null)) && captureUri != null) {```
Hope it will help anyone.